# How to make the width of GridViewColumn equal the width of Grid

Tags: .net, wpf, listview, layout

I have a 2X2 Grid that is filled with 2 Listview controls and some buttons and textboxes on my main app window. Below is part of my XAML code:

```
<Grid Name="Gd">    
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListView MinHeight="600" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="330" Header="Module ID" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

    <ListView MinHeight="600" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="330" Header="Module Name" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>    
</Grid>
```

The difficulty I have got here is that I don't know how to set the width that equals the width of Grid column. Should I do it in the code behind? Also, another problem is that the above code can't handle the situation where Grid is resized.

Ideally, I want the ListView control to fill the Grid column and expand/shrink accordingly whenever the size of Grid changes. I guess it has something to do with the ColumnDefinition Settings, which I am not very sure of.

Can anyone help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think I don't really understand the question. Which ListView do you want to AutoResize? I copied the code you provided above, changed the `Grid.Column` of the second ListView to 1 and it seems to work as expexted: both ListView size together with the Grid.

Comment: try setting horizantalalignment to stretch for both list view and grid view

Comment: exactly, just wanted to add that: Remove the `Width` from the GridViewColumn and set `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` for both ListViews

Comment: Yes, thanks everyone. `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are putting your ListView in the first column, your column definitions should looks like the following:

```xml
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>             
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />           
   <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />         
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Aslo, as guys already said, set `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` for both `ListView` controls

Answer (score 0):

try this....
if you want equal height for both ListViews then you can specify rowdefinition height as * or else you can give auto.....

```
<Grid Name="Gd">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="330" Header="Module ID"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

        <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="330" Header="Module Name" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>
```